# How can you fit a mathematical model to data while varying which model parameters are free vs. fixed for different invocations of the optimizer?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, model-fitting

Suppose you have a mathematical model that you wish to fit to some data. The model has some parameters that are always fixed and other parameters which may be free or fixed for any particular run of the optimizer. In my use case, some of the fixed parameters are time series represented as vectors and others are scalars. The reason that some of the parameters may be free for some runs of the optimizer and fixed for others is because some parameters of the model need to be determined using truncated data (only a portion of the fixed time series data is used when fitting these parameters) whereas the remaining free parameters are determined using the complete time series data and treating the previously-determined parameters as fixed in a subsequent run of the optimizer.

For example, the cost function for a least squares fit of the model would be something like:

```
function cost = ComputeCost(modeledSignal, empiricalSignal)
    % modeledSignal and empiricalSignal are vectors of equal length
    m = length(modeledSignal);
    err = modeledSignal - empiricalSignal;
    cost = 1/(2*m)*sqrt(err*err');
end
```

The model function might be something like this (this isn't my actual model):

```
function fittedSignal = ModelFunction(freeParameters, fixedParameters)
    freeParam1 = freeParameters(1);
    freeParam2 = freeParameters(2);
    freeParam3 = freeParameters(3);

    t = fixedParameters.Time;
    someData1 = interp1(t, fixedParameters.MeasurementSeries1, t - freeParam1, 'spline', 0);
    someData2 = interp1(t, fixedParameters.MeasurementSeries2, t - freeParam1, 'spline', 0);
    someScalar = fixedParameters.Scalar1;
    
    fittedSignal = freeParam2*someData1 + freeParam3*someData2 - someScalar;
end
```

To fit the model parameters we'd do something like:

```
initialEstimate = rand(1,3)*10;
lb = zeros(1,3);
ub = ones(1,3)*10;
opts = optimoptions('patternsearch');
timeStep = 1.34;
fixedParameters.Time = 1:1000*timeStep;
fixedParameters.MeasurementSeries1 = rand(1,1000)*349.2;
fixedParameters.MeasurementSeries2 = rand(1,1000)*87.43 - 10.23;
fixedParameters.Scalar1 = 9.2;

truncationLimit = 50;
truncatedFixedParameters.Time = fixedParameters.Time(1:truncationLimit);
truncatedFixedParameters.MeasurementSeries1 = fixedParameters.MeasurementSeries1(1:truncationLimit);
truncatedFixedParameters.MeasurementSeries2 = fixedParameters.MeasurementSeries2(1:truncationLimit);
truncatedFixedParameters.Scalar1 = fixedParameters.Scalar1;

% signalToBeModeled is a vector
costFunction1 = @(freeParameters) ComputeCost(ModelFunction(freeParameters, truncatedFixedParameters), signalToBeModeled);
[psolve, fval, exitflag, output] = patternsearch(costFunction, initialEstimate, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, opts);

% We want to pass in psolve(1) from the first run of patternsearch as a fixed parameter instead of letting it be free
costFunction2 = @(freeParameters) ComputeCost(ModelFunction(freeParameters, fixedParameters), signalToBeModeled);
% Do another run of the optimizer, but treat the first parameter as fixed instead of free this time
[psolve, fval, exitflag, output] = patternsearch(costFunction, initialEstimate, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, opts);
```

As written, the second call to `patternsearch` doesn't do what we want. What I'm really looking for is a way to tell the optimizer, "Hey, treat that first element of the `freeParameters` vector as a fixed value for this particular run." Is it possible to make MATLAB's optimizers fit only a subset of the free parameters, leaving the remaining ones as fixed? I used `patternsearch` in the example code, but I'd like to do this more generally for any of the MATLAB optimizers.

Basically, I was hoping there'd be a way to use the same ModelFunction for both runs of the optimizer instead of having to either write separate model functions for the case where there are 3 free parameters and the case where there are 2 free parameters or, alternately, add a bunch of conditional logic to switch the behavior to change the interpretation of the elements of the freeParameters vector, depending on the length of the vector.

Comment: Can you just set the lower and upper bounds for the "fixed" parameters equal (or very tight to) their initial values, such that it's fixed? Then you can use the the "everything" except for the variable bounds

Comment: @Wolfie That appears to work with most of the optimizers, although it can fail to work with lsqcurvefit, using either the Levenberg-Marquardt or Trust Region Reflective solvers if the "fixed" parameter isn't the last one in the parameter vector. In that case, the solver quits prematurely with the remaining parameters set to their initial estimates. That may not be too much of a problem for my use case though. I'm mostly using the MultiStart optimizer anyway. For MultiStart, the custom start points also need to be constrained to the fixed value, in addition to altering upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Your last sentence relates to what I said about having to align the initial values and bounds, good to hear it works